# How to Extend Zoom Scale in Print Preview in MS Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, print-preview

Using Excel 2016, how can i zoom in whilst in print preview ?

I can zoom in a little using, `CTRL` + `Mouse Scroll`, however, I want to have a closer view, is this possible ?

Comment: So does ctrl+ mouse scroll not work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click on the Quick Access Tollbar and then choose Customize
   Quick Access Toolbar.
2. When the Excel Options dialog box appears, choose Commands Not in
   the    Ribbon.
3. Scroll down the list until you find Print Preview Full Screen.
   Alternatively, you can click once on one of the first commands on
   the list, and then press P to jump down the list close to where
   Print Preview Full Screen resides.
4. Double-click on Print Preview Full Screen to add it to your Quick
   Access Toolbar. You can also click once on it and choose Add, but
   double-clicking saves a step. Note that it's important to choose
   Print Preview Full Screen as opposed to Print Preview and Print. The
   latter simply provides easier access to the Backstage View on the
   File menu.
5. Optionally, move Print Preview Full Screen further up the list. Each
   icon on the QAT is given a numeric keyboard shortcut. As shown in
   Figure 1, Print Preview Full Screen is the fourth icon on the list.
   This means on my computer I can press Alt-4 to display the classic
   Print Preview screen.
6. Click OK once you're satisfied with the positioning of the new icon
   on your QAT.
   [image]

**Source :** https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/restoring-classic-print-preview-in-excel-20102013

Comment: it seems great solution but zoom bar in print view seems disable,please suggest something.. @PeterH